# Is there an environment variables config file for Mac Visual Studio?

Tags: macos, azure, nuget, visual-studio-mac

I'm trying to port a project from Windows to Mac.  On Windows, he Windows project uses environment variables that are set in the Windows system itself.  On Mac it seems I have to set the environment variables from within Visual Studio on a project-by-project basis.  The six variables are the same for each project, and there are more than 30 project files, so I figure there has to be an easier way.  Is there a config file or some easier way to set these up?  Most of the variables are to access configurations for NuGet or Azure.

Comment: Are they different for each project or the same? Also not sure how they are set for each project on Windows - can you explain? On the Mac you can set environment variables globally for VS Mac by running `launchctl setenv VARNAME VARVALUE` from the Terminal.app, and then restart Visual Studio for Mac. Not sure if that helps or not.

Comment: @MattWard they're the same for each project.  On Windows they are set in the windows environment variables.  I'm going to try launchctl.

Comment: @MattWard can I manage this with a plist?

Comment: A .plist file is not used to set values when building with msbuild.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will address your needs, but we define some environment variables in a bash file which launches VS, which in turn inherits the variables:

```
export FOO=/Some/Directory/
export BAR=/Another/Directory
/Applications/Visual\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/VisualStudio
```

The variables can be referenced in the .vcxproj or .csproj project file as `$(FOO)`.

Comment: I got to the bottom of this and it turned out there was just a completely different way of doing it on the Mac.  I figured it out...eventually.

Comment: @DaveKanter Care to share your findings? We're no wiser without.

Comment: @PebermynteLars at the time I was working on the solution was that *some* of the variables could be set in Mac VS preferences directly.  But as to how to set the others, I never figured it out.  Ended up switching to a PC for the remainder of the task.